# Traversing UnsafeMutableRawPointer image data

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext

I seem to be unable to wrap my head around the methodology behind manually accessing image pixel data in Swift. I am attempting to create an image mask from a CGImage that can later be used on a separate image. I want to identify all pixels of a specific value and convert everything else in the image to black/white or maybe alpha (not really important at the moment however). The code I'm playing with looks like this:

```
    let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let contextWidth: Int = Int(snapshot.size.width)
    let contextHeight: Int = Int(snapshot.size.height)
    let bytesPerPixel: Int = 24
    let bitsPerComponent: Int = 8
    let bytesPerRow: Int = bytesPerPixel * contextWidth
    let bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)

    guard let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: contextWidth, height: contextHeight, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
        print("Could not create CGContext")
        return
    }

    context.draw(maskCGImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contextWidth, height: contextHeight))
    guard let contextDataRaw: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = context.data else {
        print("Could not get UnsafeMutableRawPointer from CGContext")
        return
    }

    let contextData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = contextDataRaw.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: contextWidth * contextHeight)

    for row in 0..<contextHeight {
        for col in 0..<contextWidth {
            let offset = (col * contextHeight) + row
            let pixelArray = [contextData[offset], contextData[offset + 1], contextData[offset + 2]]
            if pixelArray == [120, 120, 120] {
                contextData[offset] = 0
                contextData[offset + 1] = 0
                contextData[offset + 2] = 0
            }

        }
    }
```

I have tried various arrangements of the rows and columns trying to identify the correct order, i.e. `let offset = (row * contextWidth) + col`, `let offset = (col * contextHeight) + row`, `let offset = ((row * contextWidth) + col) * 3`, `let offset = ((row * contextWidth) + col) * 4`.

The output I get looks something like this (Keep in mind that this image IS supposed to look like a blob of random colors):

[image]

As my fancy little arrow shows, the black swatch across the top is my edited pixels, and those pixels are indeed supposed to be turned black, however, so are all the other gray pixels (the ones under the arrow for example). The are definitely the same RGB value of 120, 120, 120.

I know the issue is in the order that I'm moving across the array, I just can't seem to figure out what the pattern is. Also, as a note, using copy(maskingColorComponents:) won't do because I want to remove a few specific colors, not a range of them.

Any help is greatly appreciated as always. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? It should be easy to see whether you are taking as many passes across and down the image grid as you think you should be.

Comment: I've definitely tried. I've attempted to access a specific pixel (also a range of them) and color them black just to get an idea of where in the image I'm hitting when I loop through it. I've tried every rows/col combination I can think of and I still can't get the proper ordering. This is incredibly frustrating. Isn't there any standard order for this data? I wouldn't think it would be this hard!

Comment: You're obviously doing great because you've correctly hit all the pixels in the top left corner. So it just seems like your idea of what a row is might be a bit off. You are saying `for row in 0..<contextHeight` and just adding `row` to the offset, one `row` at a time, but it seems to me that the size of one `row` jump needs to be the size of _all the bytes in one row_.

Comment: @matt you were right on with this. Ended up with `let offset = (col * contextHeight) + (row * numComponents)`. So jumping to the proper row then moving along it in 4 byte steps. If you want to write that up into an answer I can mark it correct as you had the solution.

Comment: Maybe it's irrelevant for the question but shouldn't `bytesPerPixel` be 3, not 24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obviously on the right track because you've correctly hit all the pixels in the top left corner. But you don't keep going the rest of the way *down* the image; clearly you are not surveying enough rows. So the problem might be merely that you are slightly off in your idea of what a row *is*.

You are saying

```
for row in 0..<contextHeight {
    for col in 0..<contextWidth {
        let offset = (col * contextHeight) + row
```

as if adding `row` would in fact get you to that row. But `row` is just the *number* of the desired row, not the byte that starts that row; it seems to me that the size of one row jump needs to be the size of *all the bytes* in one row.